# Count movies with the word the in the title from a CSV file

Tags: python

Please, understand I am trying to learn and I'm completely new to Python.

I have a `CSV` file with columns `genre`, `title`, `director`, `actors`, `release_year`, and `release_country`, delimited by a pipe `|` sign.

Here is a sample of the `CSV` file contents:

```
genre|title|director|actors|release_year|release_country
Horror|Nosferatu|FW Mernau|Alexander Granach/Greta Schroder/Gustav von Wangenheim/Max Schreck|1922|Germany
Horror|Let the Right One In|Tomas Alfredson Henrik Dahl/Kare Hedebrant/Karin|2008|Sweden
```

What I'm trying to do is to count movies with the word `the` in the `title` field, grouping them by `genre` and have an output like this:

```
Horror: 6 titles with "The"
Action: 5 titles with "The"
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```py
import re

file = open("film_dataset.csv", mode ="r").readlines()
print(file)


with open("film_dataset.csv",mode = "r")as file:
    film_data = file.read().splitlines()
for x in film_data:
    list_= x.split(",")
    print(list_)
```

and

```py
 if  list_[0] == "Horror"
n = len(re.findall("The",film_data)
print(n)
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    n = re.findall("The",film_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I also tried

```
horror = 0 
f = open("film_dataset.csv", "r") 
for row in f: 
       cols = row.strip().split(",") 
       match = re.findall("The"*,f))
              if cols[0] == "Horror": 
                     horror += 1 


print("Horror count:", horror)
```

But that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Show a sample of the csv and the expect result output

Comment: Image removed..but I don't see an issue with how I described the problem and expected output ?

Comment: So, let's try to rethink your question. You have a CSV file listing movies with columns `genre`, `title`, `director`, `actors`, `release_year`, and `release_country`, right? And you are trying to count movies whose titles have the word `the` in them, grouping by `genre`. Is that correct? If it is, I will try to clarify and improve the question.

Comment: Hi Accdias Yes that exactly what I'd like..and I'm really sorry for not making that clearer in my post.

Comment: Reworked the question. Check it out to see if it describes what you have in mind.

Comment: That's a way more detailed way of asking the question and I'm sorry for the lack of detail on my part.Thank you accdias.that is exactly what I wanted to ask

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: If you want only those title that starts with 'THE', then you can extract only those rows which start with 'THE'. Then you can use the groupby/aggregate method to get the count.

```
df1 = df[df.Film.str.startswith('THE')]
result = df1.groupby('Genre')['Film'].count().to_dict()
```

Case 2: when 'THE' can be anywhere in string -

```
df1 = df[df.Film.str.contains('THE')]
result = df1.groupby('Genre')['Film'].count().to_dict()
```

Comment: There is no reference in the question about `pandas`. Why suggest something `pandas` related when the OP clearly has just started using Python?

Comment: I really appreciate your answer Nk03..but as accdias said I'm not using pandas or CSV module...preferably I'd like to do this without importing.

Comment: @accdias it's one of the best ways to solve the issue :)

Comment: Sure, it is, @Nk03. But bear in mind the OP stated he's just started coding in Python. The `csv` module is an easier way for someone who is starting.